# How to concatenate multiple ternary operator in PHP?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I use ternary operators alot but I can't seem to stack multiple ternary operator inside each other.

I am aware that stacking multiple ternary operator would **make the code less readable** but in some case I would
like to do it.

This is what I've tried so far :

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = ( $foo == 1 ) ? "1" : ( $foo == 2 ) ? "2" : "other";
echo $bar; // display 2 instead of 1
```

What is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Those parenthesis are what I think is getting you.

Try

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = ($foo == 1) ? "1" : (($foo == 2)  ? "2" : "other");
echo $bar;
```

Answer (score 26):

The problem is that PHP, *unlike all other languages*, makes the conditional operator left associative. This breaks your code – which would be fine in other languages.

You need to use parentheses:

```
$bar = $foo == 1 ? "1" : ($foo == 2 ? "2" : "other");
```

(Notice that I’ve removed the other parentheses from your code; but these were correct, just redundant.)

Comment: "_Notice that I’ve removed the other parentheses from your code; but these were correct, just redundant_" - but with a parser like that, you can never be sure... ;-)

Answer (score 12):

You need some parentheses around the *right* hand operand:

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = ( $foo == 1 ) ? "1" : (( $foo == 2 ) ? "2" : "other");
echo $bar;
```

PHP's interpreter is broken, and treats your line:

```
$bar = ( $foo == 1 ) ? "1" : ( $foo == 2 ) ? "2" : "other";
```

as

```
$bar = (( $foo == 1) ? "1" : ( $foo == 2)) ? "2" : "other";
```

and since that left hand expression evaluates as "true" the first operand of the remaining ternary operator ("2") is returned instead.

Comment: -1 Broken? The parser behaves exactly as defined by PHPs operator precedence and associativity overview: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @nikic PHP's manual documented the implementation - the documents don't _define_ the implementation, as PHP never had a formal specification.  The implementation is broken (i.e. different) when compared to every other language that supports the ternary operator.

Comment: If you meant to say that it was different to what you are used to, why not say just that?

Comment: @nikic I said exactly what I meant to say. Any sane language "design" would have followed the precedent set by C, C++, Java, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Put parenthesis around each inner ternary operator, this way operator priority is assured:

```
$bar = ( $foo == 1 ) ? "1" : (( $foo == 2 ) ? "2" : "other");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write this correctly thus:

```
$bar = ($foo == 1) ? "1" : (($foo == 2) ? "2" : "other");
```

(i.e.: Simply embed the 'inner' ternary operator in parenthesis.)

However, I'd be *really* tempted not to do this, as it's about as readable as a particularly illegible thing that's been badly smudged - there's never any excuse for obfuscating code, and this borders on it.

Answer (score 4):

Just stack up the parenthesis, and you've got it:

```
$bar = ($foo==1? "1" : ($foo==2? "2" : "other"));
```

As an aside, if you've got many clauses, you should consider using a `switch`:

```
switch ( $bar ) {
  case 1:  echo "1";
  case 2:  echo "2";
  default: echo "other";
}
```

If the switch gets long, you can wrap it in a function.

Comment: This is a good example of why the `switch` statement is flawed.  This example does not have any `break;` lines, so `"2"` will unintentionally be echoed for `case 1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = ( $foo == 1 ) ? "1" : (( $foo == 2 ) ? "2" : "other");
echo $bar;
```

Just use extra ( ) and it will work

Answer (score 2):

Add the parenthesis:

```
$bar = ( $foo == 1 ) ? "1" : (( $foo == 2 ) ? "2" : "other");
```