# PHP question mark operator and string concatenation

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

I'm still a newbie in php and I'm using codeigniter for my backend framework.
I have a `table.php` file that will generate a html table in real-time. Then, I encounter some issues.

```
$output_string .= "<td>".($row->isactive == "0") ? "Activated":"Deactivated"."</td>";
```

with the above code I get nothing, but with a little change to:

```
$isactive = ($row->isactive == "0") ? "Activated":"Deactivated";
$output_string .= "<td>".$isactive."</td>";
```

I get my results, so my question is, why?

Doesn't PHP support question mark operator in string concatenation??

Comment: In addition to the answers listed below, it should be noted that the `?` operator in `PHP` acts a little differently than the same operator in **every other language.**  The problem is that PHP, unlike all other languages, makes the conditional operator left associative. This breaks your code – which would be fine in other languages. -> from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203026/how-to-concatenate-multiple-ternary-operator-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does support it, just put some parenthesis around it:

```
$output_string .= "<td>".(($row->isactive == "0") ? "Activated":"Deactivated")."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not putting enough parentheses. Try this instead:

```
$output_string .= "<td>".(($row->isactive == "0") ? "Activated":"Deactivated")."</td>";
```

Note the extra set of parentheses.

If you just put:

```
$output_string .= "<td>".($row->isactive == "0") ? "Activated":"Deactivated"."</td>";
```

The PHP interpreter will try and display `$row->isactive == "0"`, so for it to do what you want, you must enclose it in an extra set of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Not like that,but after the ":" operator your

```
:"Deactivated"."</td>";
```

should be treated as single statement for false,if you want to got this try like

```
$output_string .= "<td>".(($row->isactive == "0") ? "Activated":"Deactivated")."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the entire ternary operation in a `()` brackets

```
$output_string .= "<td>".($row->isactive == "0" ? "Activated":"Deactivated")."</td>";
```

That will give you what you want.

My guess of what was happening is, `"<td>"` is appened the boolean result of `($row->isactive == "0")` and you would always get `"Activated</td>"` as your result.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation in PHP have higher priority than ternary operator. So first execute expression `"<td>".($row->isactive == "0")`, then result of it expression (it allways is equal `true`, because convertation non-empty string to boolean value interpreted as `true`). So, result of your code always is word `Activated`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work when you use `()` after and before concatenation like this

```
$output_string .= "<td>".(($row->isactive == "0") ? "Activated":"Deactivated")."</td>";
```