# Unexpected result from double ternary

Tags: php

The following results in `$c` getting 'a', when intuition says it should get `tie`. What is going on here?

```
$a = 3;
$b = 3;
$c = $a === $b ? 'tie' : $a > $b ? 'a' : 'b';
var_dump($c); // shows a
```

Comment: @RB, thanks! [The answer from Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203072/66580) explained why this is the case.

Comment: welcome @MajidFouladpour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo need to put the code between `()`

```
    $a = 3;
    $b = 3;
    $c = ($a === $b ? 'tie' : ($a > $b ? 'a' : 'b'));
```

Comment: [Due to `precedence`.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: It seems we only need one set of grouping as this produces correct results for all cases: `$c = $a === $b ? 'tie' : ($a > $b ? 'a' : 'b');`

Comment: @MajidFouladpour yes you only need one but for me is more readable like this

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 3;
$b = 3;
$c = ($a === $b) ? 'tie' : (($a > $b) ? 'a' : 'b');
var_dump($c);
```